# What causes the "Make sure that the file is a valid .NET Framework assembly." error?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I installed Quartz.NET using NuGet (>install-package Quartz).  I can see that Quartz ver. 2.2.3.400 is installed and referenced in my project.

I have the following code snippet that is creating a Quartz ScheudleFactory:

```
    public BaseServiceConfig()
        : base()
    {
        ScheduleFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();  <-- error occurs here
    }
```

and the base() is:

```
    public BaseConfig()
    {
        this.ConfigFileName = "config.xml";

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ConfigFileName))
            this.ConfigFilePath = FindConfigPath(this.ConfigFileName, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
    }
```

When I try to run this program I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in DelphiaLibrary.dll

Additional information: The type initializer for 'Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory' threw an exception.

InnerException: Make sure that the file is a valid .NET Framework assembly.
```

This has been working in the past and for some reason today it is throwing this error.  Any ideas on what this means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when the dlls in your project are different bitness. So for example, you r .Net process starts up in 32 bit mode but then you try and load a dll that tagets 64 bits. Or viceversa.